# How to securize the values per each column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

My inputs are a DataFrame and a Dictionnary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', None, '2'],
 'B': ['baz', '1', '4'],
 'C': [None, 'bar', None],
 'D': [None, None, None]})

#      A    B    C   D
# 0  foo  baz  NaN NaN
# 1  NaN    1  bar NaN
# 2    2    4  NaN NaN

dict_ = {
    "A": "CONDTIONNAL",
    "B": "MANDATORY",
    "C": "MANDATORY",
    "D": "OPTIONAL"
}
```

And I expect a multistring as an output :

```
"""
    Column A is OK
    Column B is OK
    Column C is not OK / values missing at [0, 2]
    Column D is OK
"""
```

I started by cheking if the values are null but unfortunately the values get collapsed :

```
df.isnull().any().to_dict()

{'A': True, 'B': False, 'C': True, 'D': True}
```

Can you help me make out the multistring, please ? Ideally, I would be more than happy if we can make a custom func that will return a boolean: `True` if all the columns are valid, `False`, otherwise.

Comment: What does the `CONDTIONNAL` input mean?

Comment: Hi. It's ok to have `nan` values for a `CONDTIONNAL` column.

Comment: So basically they're not to be validated at all?  How does that differ from `OPTIONAL`?

Comment: Why not ? A, B and D are valid based on my logic. To make it simple, you can assume `OPTIONAL` and `CONDTIONNAL` are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using boolean operations:

```
# flag invalid rows when value is MANDATORY
invalids = df.isnull() & pd.Series(dict_).eq('MANDATORY')

# get invalid indices
idx, cols = np.where(invalids)
# aggregate as list
rows = pd.Series(idx, index=df.columns[cols]).groupby(level=0).agg(list)

# for each column, display report
for i, (col, invalid) in enumerate(invalids.any().items()):
    suffix = f'not OK / values missing at {rows[col]}' if invalid else 'OK'
    print(f'    Column {col} is {suffix}')
```

Output:

```
    Column A is OK
    Column B is OK
    Column C is not OK / values missing at [0, 2]
    Column D is OK
```

For a multistring:

```
'\n'.join([f'    Column {col} is {f"not OK / values missing at {rows[col]}" if invalid else "OK"}'
           for i, (col, invalid) in enumerate(invalids.any().items())])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this accuracy. About the custom function, I will return the value of `invalids.any().any()` (not sure if it's good). Have a beautiful day.

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this.

```
mandatory_columns = ['B', 'C']
col_null_indices = {col: set(df[df[col].isnull()].index) for col in mandatory_columns}

for col_name, col_null_indices in col_null_indices.items():
    if col_null_indices:
        print(f"Column {col_name} has null values at indices {col_null_indices}")
    else:
        print(f"Column {col_name} has no null values")
```

For your data, this prints out

```
Column B has no null values
Column C has null values at indices {0, 2}
```

Comment: Thank you AKX! FYI, in my post, I gave an exact output that I'm expecting. Also, there is a second part where I talk about a custom function. I'll start from your answer to see if I can make it.

Comment: You should have no problem adapting this code to the exact output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_dataframe(df, dictionary):
  result = []

  for col, condition in dictionary.items():
      if condition == "MANDATORY":
          missing_idx = df.index[df[col].isnull()].tolist()
          if missing_idx:
              result.append(f"Column {col} is not OK / values missing at {missing_idx}")
          else:
              result.append(f"Column {col} is OK")
      elif condition == "OPTIONAL":
          result.append(f"Column {col} is OK")
      elif condition == "CONDITIONAL":
          result.append(f"Column {col} is OK")

  return "\n".join(result)

output = check_dataframe(df, dict_)
print(output)
```